# N_gram counter implementation for an argument n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I'm doing some excercises to improve my skills, and got one to implement a bigram counter. I managed to do that pretty easily, but then started to think how would I implement an n_gram model and couldn't succeed in doing so. Something in generalizing a specific n to an n that the function gets as argument is difficult for me and I ask for assistance.

The arguments for my function would be:

- data (a list of strings) : ["I", "love", "coding", "in" "python"]
- n : the n_gram required

For a use case in which n=2:
we'll get back a counter object with this count:

- ("I", "love") : 1
- ("love", "coding") : 1
- ("coding", "in") : 1
- ("in", "python") : 1

For a use case in which n=3:
we'll get back a counter object with this count:

- ("I", "love", "coding") : 1
- ("love", "coding", "in") : 1
- ("coding", "in", "python") : 1

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It should be a simple iteration, but I found this on a search def ngrams(n, tokens): return zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)]) Why were you thinking Counter?

Comment: I ask about Counter because it sounds like nltk (which coincidentally has its own ngram module, I think.

Comment: Hi, my wish is to create such working code myself.
I wish to count the number of occurances for each such tuple.
but I don't know how can I perform such action when the n is an argument.